# Custom Delegate is not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have my **first** `viewController` "SFCrearMomentoViewController" and the **second** view is a `tableViewController` "MasterViewController". I need to select a row `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and call the method `didCelected` which is implemented in my "first viewController" and close the view using `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

The problem is that the method `didCelected` is never called. I've already tested this code in a test project using "two viewControllers" and it works but I don't know what's the problem in my current project.

`SFCrearMomentoViewController.h`

```
...
#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface SFCrearMomentoViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, MasterViewControllerDelegate>{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
}
...
```

`SFCrearMomentoViewController.m`

```
...
-(void)didSelected:(NSString *)nombre{
    NSLog(@"didSelected method %@", nombre);
}


@end
```

`MasterViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MasterViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void) didSelected:(NSString *)nombre;

@end

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MasterViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

`MasterViewController.m`

```
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.delegate didSelected:@"row selected"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
...
```

Solution: I had to set the delegate self. I implemented it in the *Segue*.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MasterViewController class]]) {
        MasterViewController *nextView = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextView.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually set the delegate?

Comment: Where have you set the delegate in the ViewController class? and where have you defined the function in the controller class?

Comment: in MasterViewController.h @HermannKlecker

Comment: @KhawarAli Yes in the view controller class "MasterViewController.h" and the function in "SFCrearMomentoViewController.m"

Comment: Could you show that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate in SFCrearMomentoViewController, you can do it in viewDidLoad, for example.

```
masterViewController.delegate = self;
```

I assume that you allocated and initialised new masterViewController object of MasterViewController type.

Comment: Thanks! in my case I implemented it in the Segue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few hours ago. In my case I set the delegate in prepareForSegue to the segue.destinationViewController but my destination view controller wasn't the View Controller with the delegate, it was a UINavigationController. 
So I used this one:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"modalNeuerRaum"])
    {
        [(MyCustomModalViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController viewControllers][0] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

That worked for me, but I don't know if you have a UINavigationController..

Comment: Thanks! my problem was something like that. I edited the question and added the solution code